# Is it possible to send more than two arguments with reply.view in HAPIJS

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

In my module.exports:

```
module.exports.getselectedtimeperiod = function getselectedtimeperiod (request, reply) {
  var from = request.query.from || Moment().subtract(5, 'day')
  var to = request.query.to || Moment.now()
  var fromDate = Moment(from).unix()
  var toDate = Moment(to).unix()
  var url = config.LOG_SKOLESKYSS_GET_APPLICATIONS + fromDate + '/' + toDate
  Wreck.get(url, wreckOptions, function (err, data, payload) {
    if (err) {
      reply(err)
    }   
    request.yar.set({'sokerdata': payload})
    reply.view('show-applicants', payload)
  })
}
```

I would like to send to my views the "payload" and "viewOptions" which contains (title for tab), and other defined variables in the package.json file.
is there any way to overcome this problem? 
ofcourse getting errors when trying to do it like this:

```
reply.view('show-applicants', payload, viewOptions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to send to your views, I think you can pass an object instead.

```
reply.view('show-applicants', {
  payload: payload,
  viewOptions: viewOptions
});
```

Then in your view ex. handlebars, you can access variables with:

```
{{payload}} and {{viewOptions}}
<!-- or {{payload.someKey}} in case of access key in object -->
```